# Distributing APK splits with Firebase App Distribution

Tags: firebase, firebase-app-distribution, app-distribution

“Is it possible to use Firebase App Distribution with APK split? It doesn't declare a dependency on `assemble` task, are there any workarounds for this?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the gradle plugin is that it

1. doesn't declare dependency on `assemble` task (in general, regardless of apk splits, by gradle convention, you shouldn't just "expect" the apks to be there)
2. doesn't generate tasks per apk splits -- but you do for flavors

Try the following work around:

```
// Generate firebase app distribution task variants for all abis
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
variant.outputs.all { output ->
def abi = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)

if (abi == null) return
def abiName = abi.replace("_", "").replace("-", "")
task("appDistributionUpload${abiName.capitalize()}${variant.name.capitalize()}", type: com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.UploadDistributionTask_Decorated) {
appDistributionProperties = new com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.AppDistributionProperties(
new com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.AppDistributionExtension(),
project,
variant
)
appDistributionProperties.apkPath = output.outputFile.absolutePath
appDistributionProperties.serviceCredentialsFile = project.file("secrets/ci-firebase-account.json")
appDistributionProperties.releaseNotes = abi
appDistributionProperties.groups = "ra-testers"
 
// Add dependsOn respective assemble task, so it actually
// builds apk it wants to upload, not just expect it to be there
dependsOn "assemble${variant.name.capitalize()}"
}
}
}
```